# What does $(G:G')$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to teach myself some ring theory from a book, and have come across this sentence:

"There are $(G:G') = 4$ linear characters"

where $G$ is a group, and $G'$ is the derived group. I understand what a derived group is, and I understand the concept of a group character, it's the notation $(G:G')$ that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: It seems oddly similar to the index of a subgroup: $[G:G']$ that indicates the number of classes of the quotient $G/G'$ where $G'$ is a normal subgoup of $G$ (wich is the case for the derived group).

Comment: Ah yeah, it must be that. Thanks!

Comment: @DarthGeek The index of a subgroup is well defined even if the subgroup is not normal. Indeed, $[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, come to think of it it's not *really* the number of classes of the quotient but the number of *lateral classes* (so indeed, the subgroup need not be normal). Also, your identity is only true for finite group and subgroup.

Comment: Right. In general it's the number of cosets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just different notation for the index $[G:G']$ where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup. Since every linear character is a group homomorphism $G\to F^\times$ into an abelian group $F^\times$, they will factor through the abelianization $G^{\rm ab}:=G/G'$ as $G\to G^{\rm ab}\to F^\times$. Thus, the linear characters of $G$ are just linear characters of $G^{\rm ab}$ prepended with the quotient map $G\to G^{\rm ab}$. The number of linear characters of $G^{\rm ab}$ is equal to $|G^{\rm ab}|$, since $G^{\rm ab}$ is finite abelian, and this is $[G:G']$.